# Что же такое WebSocket

Tags: api, html, websocket, html5, сервер

Много слышал и недавно сам начал познавать технологию WebSocket. Возникло куча вопросов на которые никак не могу найти ответы. Посмотрев гугл много сайтов лишь объясняют  создание собственного сервера WebSocket или готовые коды чатов.

Не могли бы Вы подсказать какие-то учебнички по освоению WebSocket, интересно понять как это происходит. Еще интересно, как происходит к примеру в некоторых играх передвижение персонажа.

Заранее благодарен, очень необходима помочь, без Вас никак ;(

Comment: не вижу смысла давать какие-либо ссылки на литературу - вы же их уже нагуглили, да так ничего и не поняли. попробуйте задать конкретный вопрос

Comment: Вы статью в википедии для начала читали? Там довольно доступным языком написано что это такое и как оно работает. Для начала хватит. Но причем тут движение персонажа в играх?

Comment: @manticore если есть ещё интерес могу поделиться опытом